# How to use firebase with ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a situation when I have large set of data[Approx 1000+] in firebase database and I want to show those data in ViewPager with Fragments.

So, like android firebase-ui library has adapter for ListView and RecyclerView which will handle the large data set in proper way.

Is there anything like that for adapter of ViewPager?
Or any help on how we should handle those large set of data?