# Load Large data from firebase into Viewpager

Tags: android, firebase, optimization, firebase-realtime-database

I have a situation when I have large set of data in firebase database and I want to show those data in `ViewPager` with Fragments.
The database and callbacks works fine but it clogging up the main thread when I try to add it to `ViewPager` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Im using `EventBus` for communication between the `Activity` and Singleton class to handle add firebase related taks.

Here are some code snippets

`Singleton Class`

```
databaseProjectsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
            // Get the project from the snapshot and add it to the UI
            Project project = snapshot.getValue(Project.class);
            project._id = snapshot.getKey();
            add(project, ProjectType.NORMAL);
        }
        ...
    });


private void add(Project project, ProjectType projectType) {
    if (!data.contains(project)) {
        project.projectType = projectType;
        data.add(project);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new RefreshDataEvent());
    }
}
```

`MainActivity`

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onRefreshEvent(RefreshDataEvent event) {
    if (mAdaptor != null) {
        mAdaptor.setData();
    }
}
```

`Adaptor`

```
public class ProjectAdaptor extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final EmptyInterface emptyInterface;
private List<Project> mData;

public ProjectAdaptor(FragmentManager fm, EmptyInterface emptyInterface) {
    super(fm);
    mData = new ArrayList<>();
    this.emptyInterface = emptyInterface;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    PagerFragment item = PagerFragment.newInstance(mData.get(position));
    return item;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public void setData() {
    mData = ProjectContext.getInstance().getData();
    emptyInterface.isEmpty(mData.isEmpty());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public interface EmptyInterface {
    void isEmpty(boolean isEmpty);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
The most relevant question i could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022540/how-to-use-firebase-with-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter) but with no answers.

Comment: Are you using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` or `FragmentPagerAdapter`  Also it might be helpful to see the code for the creation of your Fragments

Comment: @Jahnold I added the code for the adaptor